# Instantiate UI object in Unity and doesn't show in the screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a code like this in Unity (CSharp):

```
public GameObject button;
public GameObject panel;

void Start () {
    button.transform.SetParent (panel.transform);
    Sprite shape = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Logo");
    var img = button.transform.GetComponent("Image") as Image;
    img.sprite = shape;
    img.color = new Color (50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

Now, this is how my scene looks before Play:

[The button in the left side is the one i will try to instantiate in my code and "Albumes" is the Panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHeaO.png)

Then, when I press the Play Button I get this:

[I can see in the inspector that the sprite was successfuly loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIIRC.png)

Can somebody give me any clue about this behavior?

Comment: make sure the image component alpha is not zero and that you selected the appropriate resolution for the sprite in the inspector

Comment: Check the alpha of the sprite after it is assigned to your button. Also look at this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems like that the way you are assigning sprite is not correct. Sprite assigns through `Sprite.Create`. You can try this,

```
public GameObject button;
public GameObject panel;

void Start () {
    button.transform.SetParent (panel.transform);
    Sprite shape = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Logo");
    var img = button.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
    img.sprite = Sprite.Create(shape.texture,img.sprite.rect,new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f));
    img.color = new Color (50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a sprite from another sprites texture in order for it to change.